# java - skip button clicks with onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a button that moves around the screen and changes image and every 5th time it's pressed I want it to also do an additional function (print a command). I can't figure out how to only trigger an event every 5th button press though? I have tried counting with an int but I am getting errors about then referring to the int in the nested if condition. I had tried playing around with the final prefix but can't figure out how to get it working so that I may edit the variable both outside and inside the if condition.

Error:(58, 20) error: local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    int i=0;
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ;
            //Move position
            Random r = new Random();
            int buttonHeight;
            int buttonWidth;
            int xPos = r.nextInt(480);
            int yPos = r.nextInt(800);
            imageButton.setX(xPos);
            imageButton.setY(yPos);

            //Change image
            int[] imageIds = {
                    R.drawable.pic1,
                    R.drawable.pic2,
                    R.drawable.pic3,
                    R.drawable.pic4,
                    R.drawable.pic5,
                    R.drawable.pic6,
                    R.drawable.pic7,
                    R.drawable.pic8,
                    R.drawable.pic9,
                    R.drawable.pic10

            };
            int randomImageId = imageIds[r.nextInt(imageIds.length)];
            imageButton.setImageResource(randomImageId);
            if(i==5){
                Toast offMsg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "This is the fifth button press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                offMsg.show();
                int i=0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Declare your counter variable inside the OnClickListener:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        int i = 0;        

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ...
            if(++i == 5){
                Toast offMsg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "This is the fifth button press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                offMsg.show();
                i=0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple thing that I needed to know

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because you **can't access local variables from an inner class**.

**Declare your variable 'i' as an instance variable** i.e. define it outside addListenerOnButton()  method and remove the int i = 0 declaration from addListenerOnButton() method and also change the int i = 0 line after offMsg.show() to i = 0.

You also need to increment the variable 'i' every time the image is clicked.

Comment: Thank you, such a simple thing that I needed to know